# equivalent Update query sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

1)

```
update m 
set long_description = is null(a.[value],' ')
```

Changing to

```
 update m 
set long_description = CASE WHEN a.[name] = 'long description' THEN is null(a.[value],' ') END
```

But the query not updating values, please help with correct query with case

Comment: What is the dbms?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please add a tag to your question indicating your dbms (e.g. sql server), and edit the question to explain what logic you'd like your update statement to apply.

Comment: `is null` is not a function.  The right way to spell it, actually, is `COALESCE()`.

Comment: thanks , but running below queries giving different results   update m 
set 
     long_description = 
        case when  a.name = 'longdescription' 

then
  COALESCE(a.[value],' ')  end
,colour =         case when  a.name = 'color' 
then 
     COALESCE(a.[value],' ')  end
     
   

from dbo.Media_Services as m,
dbo.promo_Items as p,  
dbo.PROMO_ITEM_ATTRIBUTES as a
where p.article_number = m.Item_Number
and p.style_id = m.Master_ID
and p.id = a.promo_item_id
--and a.name in ('longdescription','color')

;

Comment: You mean `isnull(a.[value],' ')`

Comment: yes , if null i expect ' ' else a.value

Comment: The 2 statements of course are  not equivalent.

Comment: please help me giving second statement equally

Answer (score 0):

It's not hugely clear what you want. In your first example you update Long_Description to be a.value unless it is null in which case you insert a space.

In the second example you appear to be saying if a.name has the value 'Long Description' only then set Long_Description to be a.value (unless it is null in which case use a space).

Are you trying to do this (change long_description to a.value if a.name is the same as long_description) ?

```
update m 
set long_description = CASE WHEN a.[name] = long_description
                            THEN isnull(a.[value],' ') END
```

If not you need to clarify your question so we know what it is that you want.

Comment: update m 
set long_description = isnull(a.[value],' ')
from dbo.AAA as m,
dbo.BBB as p, 
dbo.CCC as a
where p.article_number = m.Item_Number
and p.style_id = m.Master_ID
and p.id = a.promo_item_id
and a.[name] = 'longdescription'

update m 
set Colour = isnull(a.[value],' ')
from dbo.AAA as m,
dbo.BBB as p,  
dbo.CCC as a
where p.article_number = m.Item_Number
and p.style_id = m.Master_ID
and p.id = a.promo_item_id
and a.[name] = 'color'   we have these 2 update queries now am trying to combine to one query

Comment: update m 
set 
     long_description = case when a.[name] = 'longdescription'
       then isnull(a.[value],' ')
           end 

 ,colour = case when a.[name] = 'color'
     then isnull(a.[value],' ')
     end
 
from dbo.AAA as m,
dbo.BBB as p,  
dbo.CCC as a
where p.article_number = m.Item_Number
and p.style_id = m.Master_ID
and p.id = a.promo_item_id

;

Comment: but not updating

Comment: vijay - add your detail to the original post. It's impossible to read in comments. Also, I don't understand your comments.